# Inquisitive badge is far too easy to obtain

Tags: discussion, badges

The criteria for the curious and inquisitive badges are far too easy to obtain.

As an example,
[this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1833945/andreanobili?tab=questions&sort=votes&page=6) has only about a third of the questions with a positive count. So two thirds of the questions were either ignored or not well received. Is this really behaviour to be encouraged by awarding an inquisitive (silver) badge?

Comment: The badge description includes "... and maintained a positive question record". Wouldn't they fail this condition if two thirds of their question were ignored or not well received?

Comment: I think as long as he has more upvotes than downvotes on his questions he will stay in the black. But perhaps a question with no upvotes shouldn't count as a well received question.

Comment: The user still has a positive question record; they don't have enough posts that are closed or deleted or with a *negative* score to bring the ratio down.

Comment: Also, the user asked nearly 500 questions and did not get the gold Socratic badge. They did not get their Inquisitive badge easily if they needed to ask hundreds of questions.

Comment: Several questions with thousands of views but a vote count of only +1. That suggests the titles are "click bait": they promise to be useful for a commonly found problem but do not provide useful information about that problem.

Comment: The badge was designed to make [question grinding difficult](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4897/how-curious-are-you-or-tallied-elu-asking-day-badges-proposal-results).  I think it safe to say that not many people will ask 500+ questions in order to get a silver badge. It's also clear that the badges did not motivate the questions in this case, since the user didn't know the badge would exist when they asked most of their questions. So while we didn't eliminate _every_ edge case, we made it a lot harder to get silver or gold than _just_ asking a lot of questions.

Answer (score 19):

That user did **not** get the badge easily

They have asked nearly 500 questions but *don't have a Socratic badge yet*! That Inquisitive badge only required 30 days with good questions, the question to ask is why they haven't reached 100 such days yet.

Their *overall* record is good enough. With so many questions asked, their ratio of downvoted, closed or deleted posts against their total has not fallen below 0.5; e.g. more than half of those questions were *not terrible*. Remember that a post that is downvoted *and*  closed *and* deleted counts 3 times in that formula.

Purely from their *current stats* you'd expect them to have the Socratic badge already, see [this data explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/202534/asking-over-time-badges?UserId=1833945). What that query cannot take into account is deleted posts however. Clearly there have been at least some deletions, making any day with questions that are now deleted ineligible for the badge.

All this means that the goals for the badges are being met!

And just to be explicit: The badge is *not* awarded because you asked great questions! That's what the per-question badges are for. The badge is there to reward *regularly asking questions*, without allowing you to game the system by throwing bad (off-topic, low quality) questions at the site. And that's exactly what this user has been doing, asking regularly.

Comment: When someone has 500 questions having around half of them be bad questions is *hundreds of bad questions*.  That's a real problem.  A *real* problem.  Having half of your questions be bad questions when you have 10 is one thing, but if someone is failing to learn how to ask good questions fairly regularly once they have more than several dozen they're doing something really wrong.  These patterns are indicative of throwing a lot of crap at a wall and just seeing what sticks without just learning how to ask a good question.

Comment: @Servy: they are **not bad**. They are mediocre. If they were bad they'd be downvoted (counting once), and / or closed (counting again). As it is there are at least 19 deleted questions, so those count separately against the ratio. But as it is the user *did not piss us off*, which is what we *want*.

Comment: @Servy: the ratio calculation *already takes this into account*. This user is probably at the edge, there will *always* be edge cases, increasing the ratio or the requirements is going to shut out a whole lot of legitimate users that are doing better than this.

Comment: @Servy: the same applies to the Unsung Hero badge otherwise; if you give enough mediocre accepted answers, you get that badge. *Or* you can be answering great in a low-traffic badge, which was the goal of the badge.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Mentioned user did ruin [tag:prolog] for some time. People simply gave up on down voting him.

Comment: @false: then you only have yourself to blame that this user now has a badge. Don't stop downvoting if the user posts bad questions!

Comment: @MartijnPieters: If you consider trying to help as something to blame for (that's what the few did in the beginning), I would have to agree.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks for that  advice: My downvotes were now detected as "serial" down votes.

Comment: @false: I did **not** tell you to go downvote everything in sight, I think you very much misinterpreted that advice.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I only downvoted those that from my understanding of the matter deserved it. That again is something I have to blame myself for...